# Merge data frames as a function

Tags: r, function, merge

As a newbie user of R, I would like to understand how can I write a function that takes multiple 2 dataframes and returns the merge of it. I tried with :

```
 mer<-function(df1 , df2){
   zz <- merge(df1, df2,by.x = wt,by.y= wt, all = TRUE)
   zz[is.na(zz)] <- 0
   return(zz)
 }
```

But the error I get is

> Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must match numbers of columns

Comment: you have to define what wt is

Comment: If wt is the column name then it needs to be inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple of things.  First I would pass the variables as arguments.  It makes your function more explicit.  Second, within the `merge` function variables must be passed as parenthesis, i.e. "wt".

```
mer <- function(df1 , df2, var1, var2){
  zz <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = var1, by.y= var2, all = TRUE)
  zz[is.na(zz)] <- 0
  return(zz)
}
```

When you use `mer`, be sure to pass `var1` and `var2` as characters, i.e. `mer(d1, d2, "wt1", "wt2")`.

One last point.  If the name you are merging on is the same across data bases, (i.e. both are wt), you can simply use `by="wt"`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.it is indeed very clear now how to make use of the merge function/.